# Javascript Inheritance and Object Literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototypal-inheritance

In JavaScript, it is said that object literals have prototype linking, but
function objects have both prototype linking and a prototype property.

So, based on the above, can one say that inheritance (which uses the prototype property), is possible only with function objects (constructor version) and not with object literals?

Also, to add, the `__proto__` property is not accessible in all the browsers...

Comment: You cannot change the prototype of an existing object or specify the prototype when using an object literal, so, if I understand your question correctly, I'd say yes.

Comment: So that would refer to most of the browser behavior (except few like Firefox which allows one to set the "__proto__" linking)...So can one say Inheritance can be implemented using Object literal (but only in browsers which allow setting __proto__ link, like Firefox )?

Comment: Object literals themselves inherit from `Object.prototype`, so you're still getting inheritance, but you currently can't set up a longer prototype chain than that when using literal syntax like you can with constructors. And constructors are not the only way. You can use `Object.create` instead.

Comment: ...and inheritance doesn't use the `.prototype` property. It's only used when the object is created, but after that point, the `.prototype` of the function has nothing to do with the inheritance.

Comment: The `__proto__` property is **non**-standard and even deprecated in FF. I was only talking about the official spec. But as the system says, of course every object inherits from something, the only question is whether you can influence the prototype chain or not.

Comment: Inheritance is possible with object literals using  `Object.create(proto)` method. Also, you can create an object this way that does not even inherit from the base Object (with `Object.create(null)`).

Comment: @Sim : Can you please provide an example of the same...

Comment: `var base = {}; var child = Object.create(base);`

Comment: Ok..So based on a template (base), you are cloning or creating a sub object...Is that the only way for inheritance using Object Literal syntax...

Comment: You are not cloning anything. Every JavaScript object has a hidden [[proto]] property (the exposed non-standard `__proto__` in your case). `Object.create` will assign your parent to this property. Yes, basically either use the non-standard `__proto__` or use the standardized `Object.create` if you don't want to work with constructor functions for some reason.

Comment: @Sim: I think your statement *"Inheritance is possible with object literals using Object.create(proto) method"*  is a bit confusing. You cannot set the prototype of an object with object literal syntax. In your example, `base` might have been created using an object literal, but you could also just assign it to `Func.prototype`, i.e. `Func.prototype = {...}`. `Object.create` is just another way of creating an object and has nothing to do with object literals.

Comment: @FelixKling Your statement _"Object.create is just another way of creating an object"_ is very inaccurate. It's the only way of creating plain JavaScript objects (the OP notion of "object literals") with inheritance without using function objects (constructors) with the `.prototype` property. It's the closest thing to the classical "class" based inheritance model.

Comment: @Sim: Maybe I took "object literals" too... literal. An object literal is a syntactic construct (namely `{prop: val}`), not something that exists at run time. I can live with the term "plain object" though. Don't know why you relate this to classical inheritance now, but that's not something we have to discuss ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short version**:

Yes: The prototype chain cannot be set up or modified by assigning to an object's `prototype` property. You cannot set up inheritance by creating an object with an object literal and then giving it a property called `prototype`. Such property will be called `prototype`, but will not be considered for prototypal inheritance.

**Longer:**

If you access a property that is `undefined`, that object's inheritance chain is checked. So, if `obj['prop']` is `undefined`, then `obj.prototype['prop']` will be checked. In many browsers, the `prototype` property is implemented internally as the `__proto__` property, but that is besides the point. Rather, the point is that if some property is `undefined`, the object's prototype is checked for that property.

As people have said in comments, it's only possible to bestow an object with a prototype that provides the above-described inheritance by assigning that object to a function's `prototype` property and then using that function as a constructor.

But, the `prototype` property of an object produced by constructor invokation is not `object.hasOwnProperty('prototype')`. On the other hand, if you assign a `prototype` property to an object, then that object will `object.hasOwnProperty('prototype')`, but then `object.prototype` will have nothing to do with the prototype chain—it'll just be a regular property, and will be happened to call `prototype`.

To demonstrate this:

```
var foo = {};
foo.prototype = {bar: 'hello'};
console.log(foo.bar); // undefined
console.log(foo.prototype); // Object {bar: "hello"}
console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty('prototype')); // true

var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype = {bar: 'hello'};
var f = new Foo;
console.log(f.bar); // 'hello';
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty('bar')); // false
console.log(f.prototype); // undefined
console.log(f.hasOwnProperty('prototype')); // false
```